# Animate/Rotation/translation view on axis when user move finger on screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation

i am working on animation app which requires animation in 3D, as normal animation we can do it via core animation/ quartz-core but i need 3D with anchor point animation.

can anyone suggest me any way? so i can catch the solution.

thanks

Comment: please vist this it might be help full https://github.com/stellasdk/samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the anchorPoint of your view's layer affects the position necessarily. Here is the excellent explanation in response to this question.

[Changing my CALayer's anchorPoint moves the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968017/changing-my-calayers-anchorpoint-moves-the-view)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but i also want to scale and rotate the view, can anybody give the solution for this?

Comment: @kokx  check for the below answers for this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406372/rotate-in-z-axis-like-core-animation-slot-machine?rq=1   and also check the below blow may be this is also helpful to you.. - http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/22/3-d-rotation-without-trackball

Comment: if you want to change the color than use below function

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) ColorMonochrome
```

{
    CIImage *result = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageEdit.image CGImage]];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"];// 1
    NSLog(@"%@",[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryTileEffect]);
    [filter setDefaults]; // 2
    [filter setValue:result forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
    [filter setValue:[CIColor colorWithCGColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]] forKey:@"inputColor"];
   
    
    result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef resultRef = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];
    UIImage *resultimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultRef];
    CGImageRelease(resultRef);
    
    imageEdit.image = resultimage;
}